# how to get keys from Map scala irrespective of case

Tags: java, scala

How  do i achieve the same result in scala.

```
Map<String, Integer> lookup = 
    new TreeMap<String, Integer>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

lookup.put("One", 1);
lookup.put("tWo", 2);
lookup.put("thrEE", 3);

System.out.println(lookup.get("Two"));
System.out.println(lookup.get("three"));
```

Comment: Do you want to keep each Key as it's original value? In that case you could just insert the lowercase letters `val map = Map("One".toLowerCase -> 1, "tWo".toLowerCase -> 2, ...)`?

Comment: No this is not what i am looking for . In the above java code i can search any thing "TWO" or "twO"  and still the result come. i want my scala code to behave same without inserting more key combination inside the map

Comment: You do realize that you can use `java.util.TreeMap` from scala?

Comment: Yes i know, that will the last option but my question why scala collection is unable to do the same

Answer (score 7):

It's not that it's "unable to do the same" so much as you are unable to figure out how ;)

```
 scala> scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap("foo" -> "bar")(Ordering.by(_.toLowerCase)).get("Foo")
 res10: Option[String] = Some(bar)
```

Comment: You should be able to pass `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` instead of `Ordering.by(_.toLowerCase)`, thanks to the implicit at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L152

Comment: Yes, indeed ... But not sure why I would want that :) 
`Ordering.by` looks a lot nicer to me

Comment: I agree that `Ordering.by` looks much nicer, but for this particular case, they are not precisely equivalent. For example, http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug which I've been bitten by in the past.

Comment: I am not familiar with the issue, either he is explaining it wrong, or it's just not a problem at all: `the problem is that the dotless ‘i’ in lowercase becomes the dotless in uppercase.` That's not "the problem", but exactly the behavior that happens with every other letter and in any other language: one letter in lowercase becomes another in uppercase.

Comment: Maybe https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/java-lowercase-conversion-turkey/ does a better job of explaining. Basically `"title" == "TITLE".toLowerCase` will be `false` in Turkey. Try it out by specifying the locale: `"title" == "TITLE".toLowerCase(Locale forLanguageTag "TR")`

Comment: @Dylan That's because lowercased "TITLE" _isn't_ the same as "title" in Turkey. STRING_INCENSITIVE_COMPARATOR would not say that they are equal either. The "solution" is, like the article suggests, fix the locale. It is actually better to do with the `Ordering`, that the comparator, because the former doesn't require mutating global state.